# get from model and then set a new property on it

Tags: ember.js

I have a component:

```
App.MyChildComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  addTooltips: Ember.on('didInsertElement', function() {
    var me = this;
    var metrics = this.get('option.metrics');
    metrics.forEach(function(e, i) {
       me.get('option.metrics').objectAt(i - 1).set('tooltipDisabled', true);
    });
  });
})
```

Which is generated inside an each loop by a different component:

```
App.MyParentComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  ...
})
```

And the template of MyParentComponent is:

```
{{#each option in options}}
    {{my-child option=option}}
{{/each}}
```

All this, is called by a view with a template like this:

```
{{my-parent options=options}}
```

options is defined in the model of the view with:

```
App.MyViewModel = Ember.Object.extend({
    options: Ember.A([
        { metrics: Ember.A([
            { name: 'a' },
            { name: 'b' },
            { name: 'c' }
        ]) },
        { metrics: Ember.A([
            { name: 'd' },
            { name: 'e' },
            { name: 'f' }
        ]) },
        { metrics: Ember.A([
            { name: 'g' },
            { name: 'h' },
            { name: 'i' }
        ]) }
    ]),
});
```

When I run `me.get('option.metrics').objectAt(i - 1).set('tooltipDisabled', true);` I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: me.get(...).objectAt(...).set is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vanilla JavaScript objects don't have set methods. Use `Ember.Object`s instead:

```
App.MyViewModel = Ember.Object.extend({
    options: Ember.A([
        { metrics: Ember.A([
            Ember.Object.create({ name: 'a' }),
            // ...
        ]) }
    ]),
});
```

[Demo.](http://ember-twiddle.com/f6a6dbd262f24991375c)